# How to do aws vm incremental scan functionality?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can anyone help me with how to do an incremental scan on AWS using python SDK? I want to scan the S3 bucket of an Amazon EC2 instance. The first time it should scan completely and after that, it should scan only the change in this.

It can be done using...

- Use logs
- Consume changes (event driven)
- Use rest API

But how I did not get it?

Comment: What do you mean by "do an incremental scan on AWS"? Are you referring to scanning the disk of an Amazon EC2 instance, or reading data from an Amazon RDS database, or perhaps something else? Please Edit your question to add a _LOT_ more details.

Comment: Scan for what? Are you just wanting to know what files were added? What do you mean by "Use logs, consume changes, use rest API"?

Comment: Scan for files. Above three(use log & all) I just think using that we can done incremental scan.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand what you are 'scanning' for. Do you just want to collect a list of filenames of objects in Amazon S3? What do you want to with this information? Also, you say that you want to "scan the S3 bucket of an Amazon EC2 instance" but please note that Amazon S3 buckets are _not_ specifically associated with an Amazon EC2 instance. You can access an S3 bucket from any computer/instance.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I was created vm in aws and in this vm different files. I can add more and delete files in this. I want to scan all the files from this vm in incremental format using Python SDK.

Comment: What do you mean by "created vm in aws"? Are you referring to an Amazon EC2 instance? Any files stored in the EC2 instance would be kept on an Amazon EBS volume, not an Amazon S3 bucket. You could access the files like a normal disk. I still don't understand what you mean by "scan all the files", or "in incremental format".

Comment: Yes @JohnRotenstein sir I just want to collect a list of filenames of objects in Amazon S3 and that should be in incremental format. after first scan if any file change then only changed file should come in scan.

Comment: What do you want to do with the list of "new objects"? The best approach will depend on what you want to do with the information, and how often it is needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "incremental scan" capability in Amazon S3.

You would need to **list all existing objects**. However, you could use the `LastModified` date to determine which objects were created since a particular point in time.

Alternatively, you could **create an Amazon S3 Event to trigger an AWS Lambda function** whenever a new object is created. You could then write code in the Lambda function that extracts the name of the new objects from the `event` parameter and does *something* with it. This is effectively 'incremental', but one new object at a time.